# Combine two tab scripts to make one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-effects

I would appreciate it if someone could combine the two scripts found below. I would like to be able to combine the smooth collapsing functionality of the first script with the single-tab-expanding-at-a-time functionality from the second script. I couldn't add the the code completely so please refer to the link if needed.

I would really appreciate this!

Script 1: (complete -http://jsfiddle.net/HcJJZ/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.effects.effect.heightFade = function(o, done) {
    var el = $(this),
        mode = $.effects.setMode(el, o.mode || "show");
    el.animate({
        height: mode,
        opacity: mode
    }, {
        queue: false,
        complete: done
    });
};
$('.mytabs').tabs({
    hide: "heightFade",
    show: "heightFade",
    collapsible: true,
    selected: -1 
});
```

Script 2: (complete - http://jsfiddle.net/fb0z3ezd/4/)

```
var inactiveOpts = {
active: false,
show: {
    effect: 'blind'
}
var $tabs = $(".tabs").each(function () {
var currTab = this,
    tabsOpts = {
        collapsible: true,
        beforeActivate: function (evt, ui) {
            $tabs.not(this).tabs("option", inactiveOpts)
        },
        activate: function (evt, ui) {
            $(currTab).tabs('option', {
                show: false
            });
        }
    }
$.extend(tabsOpts, inactiveOpts);
$(this).tabs(tabsOpts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Here is JSFIDDLE: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lgpyz74/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.effects.effect.heightFade = function(o, done) {
        var el = $(this),
            mode = $.effects.setMode(el, o.mode || "show");
        el.animate({
            height: mode,
            opacity: mode
        }, {
            queue: false,
            complete: done
        });
    };
    $('#tabvanilla').tabs({
        hide: "heightFade",
        show: "heightFade",
        collapsible: true
    });

    $('#flexslider1').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        pauseOnHover: true,
        controlsContainer: ".flex-container1",
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true
    });

    $('#flexslider2').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        slideshow: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        useCSS: false,
        controlsContainer: ".flex-container2",
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true
    });
var inactiveOpts = {
    active: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'blind'
    }
}

var $tabs = $(".tabs").each(function () {
    var currTab = this,
        tabsOpts = {
            collapsible: true,
            beforeActivate: function (evt, ui) {
                $tabs.not(this).tabs("option", inactiveOpts)
            },
            activate: function (evt, ui) {
                $(currTab).tabs('option', {
                    show: false
                });
            }
        }
    $.extend(tabsOpts, inactiveOpts);
    $(this).tabs(tabsOpts);

});
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow, awesome start. You almost have it. Any chance you can make the collapsing as smooth as the expanding? Can you apply it to all tabs, even to those in the same row/group? Thank you so much!

Comment: @khangp, pls check mark for my solution if you helped;) thanx

Comment: Praguan, unfortunately, it's not quite working the way I want.  You combined the scripts as they were, but I was asking something a little different.  In the first three rows, when the tabs collapse, they collapse quickly, not smoothly.  How do you apply the smooth effect to the collapse?